# Remove id alias appending to confirmation page URL

Tags: drupal-7

I have created a basic page in Drupal 7 that acts as a custom confirmation page for a webform. The url needs to be clean and static because it will be used for adwords.

The problem is that in id is appended to the url, see example below.
http://www.dynasty-autoglass.com/contact-confirmation?sid=230

How am I able to remove this id?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom URL(s) by using Pathauto Module in Drupal 7, you can download this from [here](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto). Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: how to create this module?

Comment: Download Link is mentioned there in the post you can download it from there and enable it.

Comment: Oops I got it , you mentioned a link.

Comment: Yes I have that module installed and used it to create a custom URL. I am not sure why there is an id appended to the end of the url. I would just like the it to end as /contact-confirmation.